# jQuery Serialize form into JSON object but ignore placeholder

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, serialization

Ok A while back I found this wonderful little addon style script for jQuery that will take all fields in a form and serialize them into a JSON object. Unfortunately however. I am finding that this function will use the placeholder text if none is otherwise provided. Which if its the case the the placeholder text is the text there I would rather it be set to null.

Any ideas how I can add that into this little snip?

```
(function($) {
$.fn.serializeFormJSON = function() {

   var o = {};
   var a = this.serializeArray();
   $.each(a, function() {
       if (o[this.name]) {
           if (!o[this.name].push) {
               o[this.name] = [o[this.name]];
           }
           o[this.name].push(this.value || '');
       } else {
           o[this.name] = this.value || '';
       }
   });
   return o;
};
})(jQuery);
```

edit:
In other words the placeholder attribute could be something like `placeholder="First name"` and it seems javascript is treating that as an actual value when grabbing the inputs. So Im getting entries for a first name field (optional) as "First name". So what I'd like is to figure out how to compare the current field the above snip is on, and have it see the current placeholder for that field (if any as things like selects dont have that attribute). And if the value being pulled is a match for the placeholder attribute I want to add that field to the object being created but as `null` instead of the placeholder text

Comment: Are you saying you want to *exclude* values that are null rather than converting them to an empty string or that you want to use the string `null` for the values?

Comment: I think he means values like "please enter you name here" are being taken when they should be empty.

Comment: Essentially if the value found is the same as the placeholder I want to flag it as `null`

Comment: Can't reproduce http://jsfiddle.net/t4cVw/

Comment: You must be using a library that is processing your `placeholder` attributes by placing that in the values of the inputs. That is not standard. Which plugins are you using?

Comment: Well, @Esailija I think between you and Jacob, you gave me something to think about. I am using a canned template that did come with its share of scripts, after reading your comments, it is plausible now that I think of it the author of the template does have some trickery with the placeholder's I appreciate the notion, Im gonna go look into that now

Comment: Yup, doing a quick grep over my javascript files, right in the middle of one of the authors canned bits, is something to trigger swapping of the placeholder value for that of the actual form element value. Im gonna guess the its the Authors attempt at being a little backwards compatible. Well.. don't I feel silly now, thanks again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just clear the placeholders before you serialize?

```
function clearPlaceHolders(){
 var form = document.GetElementById("formId");
 $(form).find("input").each(function(index,el){
  el.removeAttribute("placeholder");
 }
}
```

See this for an example: http://jsfiddle.net/WjEK9/

Comment: The selector could be `"[name]"` (All elements that have defined `name` attribute), to match the "plugin" :P

Comment: Well not exactly what I am looking for but close enough. I have since realized due to comments on the post itself, that the problem is due to the template authors trickery behind the scenes with one of there scripts. But, since I don't want to remove that from the script and its likely others will come around looking due to similar problems with canned templates, this is the one answer that best suits the overall need of the original question. Im going to end up using this as my work around :-D

Answer (score 0):

You can modify your DOCTYPE to allow a custom attribute (if you care about standards) on the input tags (or just call teh attribute "data-xxx" so "data-placeholderValue", then add the placeholder value as the value and the "placeholderValue" (for instance) then your JS can check if `value == placeholderValue` then ignore it.

An example:

**HTML:**

```
<input id="test" type="text" value="Please enter blah" placeholder="Please enter blah" />
```

**JS:**

```
var element=$('#test');
if(element.val == element.attr('placeholder')) {
  element.val(''); // Or however you want to express/capture this.
}
```

Comment: oh, theres an official placeholder attribute? Awesome! I'll amend my code.

Comment: That might work, however I am not using `data` attributes for the placeholder to swap the value out, I am using the HTML5 spec `placeholder=""` as part of the actual inputs

Comment: Tried to write an integrated version with your example.. but I'm not quite sure what the push etc bits are achieving, but hopefully you can take the logic and run with it. I'm going to bed.

Answer (score 0):

If you're referring to the placeholder attribute in HTML, I'm fairly certain that the placeholder attribute is exposed as .placeholder and not .value.

Are you using the placeholder attribute or using a script to swap a placeholder in and out of the value?

Comment: I am using the actual `placeholder=""` attribute on the input itself, no script swapping